# Meaning of defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

Tags: python, defaultdict

What is the meaning of the following line in Python?

```
x = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
```

Comment: [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's resolve it from the inside out. Firstly, [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) is the dictionary type. Like other types, calling it creates an instance (also known as object) of that type. A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a type that takes a callable parameter: something that, when called, produces an item to put in the dictionary. This happens when an entry is accessed that was not present, instead of producing a [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) like an ordinary `dict`. Thirdly, [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) is a way to create unnamed functions based on a single expression, so these two are similar (the second holds a function that knows its own name, the first doesn't):

```
y = lambda: defaultdict(dict)

def y():
    return defaultdict(dict)
```

And finally the whole thing is wrapped in another `defaultdict`. So the result is that `x` is a `defaultdict` that produces `defaultdict`s that produce `dict` instances. At the third level there aren't defaults anymore.

Comment: great explanation , I was struggling to explain it to the OP. thanks.